# Select data of all datetimes

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime

I currently have two queries, one which displays all data (regardless of time), another which considers a time frame. I'm trying to condense these together and was wondering if mysql has something for dateTimes which acts as an "allTime" variable, that is when plugged into:
`select count(*) from table where (color = "red") and (dateMade between "allTime" and "allTime");`
would display the row count of where color is red, for all rows in the table. A solution I thought of was to just use a minimum date of 0000-01-01 00:00:00 and some large end bound date, but if there already exists something to solve this I thought I might as well use that.

EDIT: This would be used on more than just the example query above, with most being much longer and more complex. The purpose is to combine this with node to make functions simpler and not have to consider a special case of all data, rather just use the time frame query and return all data based on the bounds given as arguments

Comment: I think you can just remove the date clause to get your "allTime" records, so your query would look like `select count(*) from table where color = "red"`

Comment: Yes I can do that, and am doing that currently for my all data query. I'm trying to make the two queries into one however, and since my time frame query needs dates, I need to supply some sort of dates for the all time query to combine them. Sorry if I was unclear on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the variables @from and/or @to with NULL, if you don't want to restrict the data. Use IFNULL to check if the restriction is to be applied or not.

```
select count(*) 
from table 
where color = @color
and datemade between ifnull(@from, datemade) and ifnull(@to, datemade);
```

Comment: From what I've read IFNULL seems to be inefficient on large data pools, would you agree with that or is that outdated by now? Also, your solution does work but how does entering the column name make this work? I'm just confused how sql is actually reading that

Comment: IFNULL is no problem here; it's applied only once per variable (not per record). If @from is null then the criteria becomes `and datemade between datemade ...`. Same for @to. So the DBMS sees immedialtely whether it has to compare datetime with a value or not. (`isnull(datemade, something)` on the other hand would be applied per record, so that could slow down such query, but we don't do that.)

Comment: You don't enter any column names here. You have three variables: one for the color, one for the lower date limit and one for the upper one. The color is mandatory, the date limits are not; you can set them null, if you don't want to use them. Thus you have a query that can be used with an upper and lower date limit, with only one of the two or even none of them. It stays the same query, only the variables content differs.

Comment: The column I was questioning was datemade, and how you set the `between` to be `between datemade and datemade` if @from and @to are null. Thanks for your answer though and the info on how IFNULL works here

Answer (score 1):

For cases when you don't need the date range you could make part of the `where` clause a true-ish noop:

```
select ...
from tablename
where date_created between $start and $end or $start = $end
```

Then, if you need the unbounded query, just pass the same $start and $end to it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the data twice unless you really have to, you could use a "conditional aggregation" instead, e.g.

```
select
    count(*) all_count
  , count(case when dateMade between @start and @end then id end) period_count
from table 
where (color = "red")
```

To get "all time" you simply do not filter by date range in the where clause.

Note too that COUNT() function increments for any non-null value it encounters, so for the case expression it should return a column that will always be present in a row such as the primary key.

An alternative is to use SUM() instead, like this

```
select
    count(*) all_count
  , sum(case when dateMade between @start and @end then 1 else 0 end) period_count
from table 
where (color = "red")
```

Comment: So basically what you're proposing is to combine both queries into one statement with two variables and use the respective variable for whatever task I using the statement for?

Comment: yes, and it would be more efficient to pass the data once only.